# Connecting to a local network through another computer

Tags: networking

I'm not very experienced in networking setup.

My network looks like this currently:

```
Internet <=> Router <=> NAS
               ^=> My computer
```

My NAS actually has 4 network ports, 2 of which are 10GbE capable which I want to make use of on my computer (assume I have a 10GbE NIC), so I'm trying to set it up like this:

`Internet <=> Router <=> NAS <=> My computer`

I'd still like internet connectivity on my computer, whilst being able to directly access the NAS without having to go through the router, which isn't 10GbE capable.

The NAS is running OpenMediaVault, which is built upon Debian. I have tried referring to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/388479/machine-as-gateway-between-a-router-and-local-devices) to try and set up the forwarding but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

The NAS is also running a Docker daemon, which adds its own bridge interface `docker0` along with some iptables stuff, which makes it a bit more convoluted for me to understand because I don't know what a "clean" iptables is supposed to look like.

Could anyone give instructions how to set this up, preferably with explanations for what each step does? The NAS is connected to the router via `eth1`, and the interface I'm trying to use to connect to my computer is `eth3`.

**EDIT:**

As EEAA suggested I'm trying to bridge the connections instead, but it's still not working however. Here are some outputs from my troubleshooting:

`ifconfig`: (without interfaces not in question)

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:1f:6b:14:74:43  
          inet addr:192.168.1.50  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:184494453 errors:0 dropped:15 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:61722948 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12183777795 (11.3 GiB)  TX bytes:3308095544990 (3.0 TiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:1f:6b:14:74:43  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:204022329 errors:0 dropped:99 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2496398741 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:18134842309 (16.8 GiB)  TX bytes:3766713296562 (3.4 TiB)
          Memory:fb100000-fb11ffff 

eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:1f:6b:14:75:87  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:23600 errors:0 dropped:32 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9333 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3734929 (3.5 MiB)  TX bytes:837441 (817.8 KiB)
```

`route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
```

`ip addr show`:

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:1f:6b:14:74:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:1f:6b:14:75:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
217: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:1f:6b:14:74:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.50/24 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`brctl showstp br0`:

```
br0
 bridge id      8000.ac1f6b147443
 designated root    8000.ac1f6b147443
 root port         0            path cost          0
 max age          20.00         bridge max age        20.00
 hello time        2.00         bridge hello time      2.00
 forward delay        15.00         bridge forward delay      15.00
 ageing time         300.00
 hello timer           1.39         tcn timer          0.00
 topology change timer     0.00         gc timer           8.39
 flags          


eth1 (2)
 port id        8002            state            forwarding
 designated root    8000.ac1f6b147443   path cost          4
 designated bridge  8000.ac1f6b147443   message age timer      0.00
 designated port    8002            forward delay timer    0.00
 designated cost       0            hold timer         0.00
 flags          

eth3 (1)
 port id        8001            state            forwarding
 designated root    8000.ac1f6b147443   path cost          4
 designated bridge  8000.ac1f6b147443   message age timer      0.00
 designated port    8001            forward delay timer    0.00
 designated cost       0            hold timer         0.00
 flags
```

`sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`:

`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

The MAC address of my computer shows up in `brctl showmacs br0`. My computer can ping and access the NAS (192.168.1.50), but cannot ping the gateway (192.168.1.1). The NAS is unable to ping my computer, however. The NAS remains connected to the network and to the internet.

Comment: You don't need iptables or forwarding. You just need to bridge the two 10GbE interfaces. But seriously, just get a switch that's capable of 10GbE. Doing it the way you propose is very hacky and error-prone.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the cost of a 10GbE switch because they are really expensive and most of them generate a lot of noise from what I've read.

Comment: Can you clarify what did not work for you when you enabled ip forwarding and setup iptables for NATing traffic? Perhaps, provide a pastie with iptables configuration, network route (route -n) and the IP addresses of both the machines.

Comment: @vagarwal I'm actually now trying to set up a bridge instead, and I have added outputs from my troubleshooting into the question.